# Inserting into SQL Server database ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is to insert a username, and their monthly hour limit to my SQL Server database. I've used the automatically generated statements for updating and deleting. I just need to add in new users now. The code below, should work as far as I know, but it doesn't. I think it's the way I've written it.

The part in comments is what the `Userdata.aspx` file automatically generated, so I'm trying to convert it to use my 2 text boxes.

Thanks a lot.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string sql = "INSERT INTO [UserData]([UserName], [MonthlyHourLimit]) VALUES ("+ TextBox1.Text + "," + TextBox2.Text + ")";

     //INSERT INTO [UserData] ([UserName], [MonthlyHourLimit]) VALUES (@UserName, @MonthlyHourLimit)" 
     SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = sql;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about this? Are you getting an error?

Comment: THe first thing you should take care about is SQL injection. You'd better created a SqlCommand class isntance with parameters for every value, read from user. Though it's not probably your current problem

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just nothing happens when my button is clicked.

Comment: The generated code is **much better** than yours - it uses **parameters** to avoid concatenating together SQL statements and thus opening the door to **SQL injection attacks** - just **don't do it!** - never.

Comment: But the generated code doesn't help me because I can't get the data from the boxes and insert on button1_click's event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure your data source to use parameters.

```
 <asp:sqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
   SelectCommand="select [UserName], [MonthlyHourLimit] from [UserData] where UserName= @UserName"

   InsertCommand="IINSERT INTO [UserData] ([UserName], [MonthlyHourLimit]) VALUES (@UserName, @MonthlyHourLimit);"

   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>"
   RunAt="server">

   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
   </SelectParameters>

   <InsertParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="MonthlyHourLimit" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
   </InsertParameters>

 </asp:sqlDataSource>
```

UPDATE:I've forgot to mention, you would like to use [ControlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and not simple Parameter. Take a look at following snippet:

```
  <asp:СontrolParameter Name="UserName" ControlId="ddlUserNames" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>

  ...

  <asp:DropdownList
      ID="ddlUserNames"
      runat="server"
      Autopostback="True">
      <asp:Listitem Selected="True">Users</asp:Listitem>
      <asp:Listitem Value="Peter">Peter</asp:Listitem>
      <asp:Listitem Value="Jessica">Jessica</asp:Listitem>
  </asp:Dropdownlist>
```

Take a look at corresponding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkzs2t3h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page describing usage of SqlDataSource in details.

UPDATED 2: complete example in order to avoid confusion

```
 <asp:sqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
                    SelectCommand="select [UserName], [MonthlyHourLimit] from [UserData] where UserName= @UserName"
                    InsertCommand="IINSERT INTO [UserData] ([UserName], [MonthlyHourLimit]) VALUES (@UserName, @MonthlyHourLimit);"

                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>"
                    RunAt="server">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
      </SelectParameters>
      <InsertParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="UserName" ControlId="txtUserName" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="MonthlyHourLimit" ControlId="txtMonthlyHourLimit" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
      </InsertParameters>
 </asp:sqlDataSource>

 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserName" /> 
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMonthlyHourLimit" />
```

Comment: #Vittore, this approach is MUCH better and safer than trying to build a clean/safe dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: @tgolisch belive me, I know!

Comment: So if you make it use parameters in the aspx. How do you then defined them and use them in the .cs file?

Comment: You can define ControlParameter so you don't need code or you can define general parameter so you can set it from code behind, there is details explanation in second link I gave in my answer. Most likely though that you don't need to change it in code-behind for such case and instead going to use combination of ControlParameter, SessionParameter etc.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how I can get  whatever is on those boxes into the database by clicking my button

Comment: Read link about control parameter. What it does is taking value from textbox and use as parameter value. Your button should than trigger Insert on your SqlDataSource. Again, you don't need to write code to get value from control into query if you use ControlParameter, asp.net does it for you.

Comment: Yeah it's inserting things now, but it's inserting empty values for some reason. Any ideas?
               <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="MonthlyHourLimit" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
  
            </InsertParameters>

and 
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" datasourceid ="sqlDataSource1" datatextfield = "UserName">
   </asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" datasourceid ="sqlDataSource1" datatextfield = "MonthlyHourLimit">
    </asp:TextBox>

Comment: Because you need to change your `<asp:Parameter` to `<asp:ControlParamenter` and set `ControlId` property corresponding to you textboxes `ID`

Comment: Yeah, All sorted now, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
Datasource.InsertCommand is a property.
Datasource.Insert() is a method.
```

You should also use parameters.

```
datasource.insertparameters("username").defaultvalue = TextBox1.Text + "," + TextBox2.Text
```

Comment: But insertparameters isn't a method either?